# How to give background color to svg element path?

Tags: html, css, svg, svg.js

I have converted image to svg and get the path vector like below

```html
 <svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="122.000000pt" height="98.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 122.000000 98.000000"
      preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
   <metadata>
   Created by potrace 1.14, written by Peter Selinger 2001-2017
   </metadata>
   <g transform="translate(0.000000,98.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
   fill="#000000" stroke="none">

   <path d="M93 873 c-7 -3 -6 -653 0 -660 5 -4 889 -185 892 -181 1 1 35 69 74
   151 l71 147 0 273 0 272 -515 0 c-283 0 -518 -1 -522 -2z m1007 -284 l0 -251
   -66 -139 c-59 -122 -70 -138 -88 -134 -12 3 -106 23 -211 46 -104 22 -219 47
   -255 54 -36 8 -85 21 -109 30 -24 8 -56 15 -70 15 -15 0 -49 7 -75 16 -26 9
   -58 14 -71 12 -15 -3 -26 0 -29 9 -4 8 -6 145 -6 304 l0 289 490 0 490 0 0
   -251z" style="fill:green;background-color:red"/>
   </g>
 </svg>
```

What i want is to give fill the path with color any color but when i use fill it only change the color of borders not the inner color of complete path node.
I tried

```
style="fill:green;background-color:red"
```

but not working only changing border not inner?
Here is jsfiddle link [Link to example](https://jsfiddle.net/qhqa4kyq/) can any body convert and fill the path with color?

Comment: The thing is that your SVG doesn't have any "inner". Your SVG is actually what you call a border. You can't set a color for what's inside because it's not a part of your SVG.

Comment: can you please add inner how to any solution as i am not svg expert please do some think tricky

Comment: CAN YOU PLEASE ADD SOME VALUE OR LOGIC TO IT FOR INNER COLOR

Comment: can we add image  in its background

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The thing is that your `SVG` doesn't have any "inner". Your `SVG` is actually what you call a border. You can't set a color for what's inside because it's not a part of your `SVG`.

There's specified a "hole" in your image. That's the path in your code starting with `m1007` and ending with `-251z` - due to specification: "The M indicates a moveto, ... and the z indicates a closepath)".. If you remove that part you'll have the whole shape w/o the gap inside.

https://jsfiddle.net/norin89/qhqa4kyq/4/

Comment: How you guess that i have  many similar svg there is any online tool or shortcut to check the whole path so i remove that from path..

Comment: What the science behind so i too correct my other images..rapidly

Comment: I don't know any online tool to do that. You can use some app for vector graphic (e.g. Adobe Illustrator or Inkspace). Or if you want to do it directly in the code just look for `M` and `Z` inside the `path`. Due to [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataGeneralInformation): "The M indicates a moveto, ... and the z indicates a closepath)". You probably might to write some `regexp` to remove that part of `path` for you if you wan't to do it automatically.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qhqa4kyq/6/ reaL PROBLEM want to fill with color rect is no issue path have

Comment: So you need to change your shape's as I described above. Here's how: https://jsfiddle.net/norin89/qhqa4kyq/8/ - I've left only one path so you can see the difference. First remove inner part of the path (all from `M` to `Z`) so  inner is your path too. And set `fill`, `stroke-width` and `stroke` attributes. That's all!